# javascript inherited objects created new data members on assignments?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

we have a code that looks like the following:

```
var Product = function(){


    }
Product.prototype = 
    {
                GetName: function(){
            return this.name;
        },

        name: "something"
    };

var Apparel = function(){

    }

Apparel.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);

var jeans = new Apparel();
console.log(jeans.name);
console.log(jeans.GetName());

jeans.name = "Levis";
console.log(jeans.name);
console.log(jeans.GetName());
```

Output:
something
something
Levis
Levis

So, everything works as it should! but, issue is, as soon as we execute the jeans.name = "Levis" assignment we are seeing in the debugger TWO 'name's. one for the parent Product, one for Apparel. Isn't that a memory waste? since name is a property of the parent, I would expect that this property will get used, and not a new one gets created.

any ideas as to why?

thanks

Lior

Answer (score 0):

actually, as i finished typing, I realized the answer: it is actually very smart of Javascript to act in a such a way. if Product would get affected by Apparel changes, then all subsequent instances of any  Product-derived objects would carry the last changes by any derived object.

So, it is needed by a prototypical inherited language

thanks everyone, now its clear.
Lior